# Addressing object properties in python

Tags: python, object

I'm currently working on some project where I have an object within a class with two properties, 'Tags' and 'Labels', both of which are an array. Besides that I have a function in that class that will append values to one of these arrays (after checking if the values are not already in that array). My code so far is as following:

```py
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = Object()
        self.data.Labels = []
        self.data.Tags = []

    def __init(self, datapoint, data):
        #datapoint is either 'Tags' or 'Labels'
        #data is an array with multiple values
        for key in data:
            try:
                self.data.<datapoint>.index(key)
            except:
                self.data.<datapoint>.append(key)

def Object(object):
    pass
```

So for example, I could call this function to append some values to 'Tags'. In that case I want 'datapoint' to address 'Tags'. I know that this could be done as following:

```
this.data[datapoint].push(key)
```

Can this be done in a similar format in Python or do I have to add an if-statement to determine what 'datapoint' is before I append the values to either 'Tags' or 'Labels'?

Comment: `'def' != 'class'`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bad I'm sorry, fixed it

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

Comment: Seems like `self.data` should be a dictionary, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, we don't push to a list.  We append.

Try the following:

```
if not myval in self.data.Labels:
    self.data.Labels.append(myval)
```